# Removing glassfish installation from redhat

Tags: redhat, glassfish

I am trying to remove glassfish. I have put the zipped version of glassfish in /opt/glassfish4 and I have created a service using ./asadmin create-service. How can I remove glassfish from service and remove it completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to stop domains running by Glassfish by

> asadmin stop-domain

Then you need to stop Update Tool notifier process by

> cd /opt/glassfish4/bin
>
> updatetool --notifier --shutdown

Take backup of files if u want,

Delete installed folder with

> rm -fr /opt/glassfish4

You may need to check running process by ps -ef and if any kill it.

Comment: How do i unisntall service from init.d?

Comment: @Kitex Check this, http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel5-update-rcd-command/